# PopupMenuButton can't navigate to other screens

Tags: android, flutter, dart, button

I found this solution on github when directly using ontap didn't work, but apparently I am doing something wrong. I will post the code for you to see, thanks for answering.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'routegenerator.dart';


enum PopupMenuAction {

  s,

  s1,

  s2,

  s3,

  s4,

}


class Buttonall extends StatelessWidget {

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return PopupMenuButton<PopupMenuAction>(

        itemBuilder: (context) => [

              PopupMenuItem(

                child: Text('1STAR'),

                value: PopupMenuAction.s1,

              ),

              PopupMenuItem(

                child: Text('2STARS'),

                value: PopupMenuAction.s2,

              ),

              PopupMenuItem(

                child: Text('3STARS'),

                value: PopupMenuAction.s,

              ),

              PopupMenuItem(

                child: Text('4STARS'),

                value: PopupMenuAction.s4,

              ),

              PopupMenuItem(

                child: Text('5 STARS'),

                value: PopupMenuAction.s,

              )

            ],

        onSelected: (choice) {

          switch (choice) {

            case PopupMenuAction.s:

              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/s');

              break;

            case PopupMenuAction.s1:

              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/s1');

              break;


            case PopupMenuAction.s2:

              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/s2');

              break;

            case PopupMenuAction.s3:

              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/s3');


              break;


            case PopupMenuAction.s4:

              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/s4');


              break;

          }

        });

  }

}
```

After I tried to run this code, I still couldn't navigate by clicking on the popupmenuitems. I tried about three to five methods proposed online without much help, even after trying to look at some other projects code.

Comment: Can you share what's the error or problem you are facing after trying this solution?

Comment: @RohanJariwala thanks for answering. The issue is the inability to navigate to other screens despite the items being clickable.

Comment: I mean is there any error you are getting when you click on the menu item?

Comment: @RohanJariwala Everything seems to work perfectly, I tried to use the routegenerator in other ways to check it and it worked fine. So I am sure the issue comes from the code above.

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code and updated some things and it's working:

```
import 'package:demo/b.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum PopupMenuAction {
  s,

  s1,

  s2,

  s3,

  s4,
}

class Buttonall extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopupMenuButton<PopupMenuAction>(
        itemBuilder: (context) => [
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text('1STAR'),
                value: PopupMenuAction.s1,
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text('2STARS'),
                value: PopupMenuAction.s2,
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text('3STARS'),
                value: PopupMenuAction.s,
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text('4STARS'),
                value: PopupMenuAction.s4,
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text('5 STARS'),
                value: PopupMenuAction.s,
              )
            ],
        onSelected: (choice) {
          switch (choice) {
            case PopupMenuAction.s:
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(BScreen.routeName);

              break;

            case PopupMenuAction.s1:
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(BScreen.routeName);

              break;

            case PopupMenuAction.s2:
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(BScreen.routeName);

              break;

            case PopupMenuAction.s3:
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(BScreen.routeName);

              break;

            case PopupMenuAction.s4:
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(BScreen.routeName);

              break;
          }
        });
  }
}
```

here BScreen.routename is another screen

BScreen that i created

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/bscreen'; // this is name for avoiding errors

  const BScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<BScreen> createState() => _BScreenState();
}

class _BScreenState extends State<BScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

last thing we need to update/define route in main.dart

```
import 'package:demo/a.dart';
import 'package:demo/b.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
       
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(body: Buttonall()),
      routes: {
        BScreen.routeName: (ctx) => BScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

main change in main.dart is routes:{} and wrapping your home: into Scaffold.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried it but there is an error on the route name, moreover I want to keep my initial route. This code is in an add-on.dart file because I will just put it in the appear or at the bottom.

Comment: can you share your main.dart file? and error log in debug console ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here is the main file and thank you for your efforts. class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/s',
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MyHomePage(),
        '/s': (context) => HPage(),
        '/s4': (context) => HPage4(),
        '/s3': (context) => HPage3(),
        '/s2': (context) => HPage2(),
        '/s1': (context) => HPage1()
      },
    );
  }
}

Comment: can you share 'routegenerator.dart' also?